# How to get suppress ^M characters in my ClojureBox (EmacsW32) REPL connected to lein swank

Tags: emacs, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, line-endings

I am connecting to a swank server from my [ClojureBox](http://clojure.billhugh.com) install. I.e. `lein swank` from my project directory and then `M-x slime-connect` from EmacsW32.

However, when I do this I see the DOS line-endings everywhere in the REPL (`^M`). I.e.

```
user> (doc map)
-------------------------^M
clojure.core/map^M
([f coll] [f c1 c2] [f c1 c2 c3] [f c1 c2 c3 & colls])^M
  Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of applying f to the
  set of first items of each coll, followed by applying f to the set
  of second items in each coll, until any one of the colls is
  exhausted.  Any remaining items in other colls are ignored. Function
  f should accept number-of-colls arguments.^M
nil 

user> (println "foo")
foo^M
```

I'm aware that this has to do with platform encoding, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to suppress them. I poked around in the EmacsW32 menus and tried the java command line system property (in lein.bat) `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1` to no avail.

I've also found other questions about doing global find/replace of ^M within buffers - but I want to filter REPL output.

I also noticed the following in the `*inferior-lisp*` buffer:

`(do (.. java.net.InetAddress getLocalHost getHostAddress) nil)(swank.swank/start-server "c:/Users/noahz/AppData/Local/Temp/slime.4912" :encoding "iso-latin-1-unix")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have this in my .emacs:

```
(defun hide-eol ()
  "Do not show ^M in files containing mixed UNIX and DOS line endings."
  (interactive)
  (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table))
  (aset buffer-display-table ?\^M []))
```

I just call it with M-x hide-eol when required. You could bind a key, or put it in a hook of some sort if you prefer.

Credit is due to persons unknown - I copied this function from somewhere, but I don't remember where.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>C-x RET f</kbd> then type unix-undecided or similar. Then save your file. Basically, you want to change the end-of-line convention for the file.

If this is not your file and you cannot save it, you can use <kbd>M-%</kbd> then type <kbd>C-q C-m</kbd> followed by `RET` and then just `RET`, to query-replace `C-M' with nothing.

---

Oops -- scratch all of that.  I see now that you are not working with a file, but with REPL output.  Dunno whether it will help, but maybe you can still use <kbd>C-x RET f</kbd>, but enter `dos` so you at least won't see the ^Ms.  If that's not good enough, hopefully someone else will have an answer.

Comment: `unix` or `dos` are likely candidates for formats. Here's a pretty good reference on the topic: http://xahlee.org/emacs/emacs_line_ending_char.html